# Run Python modules on web host that doesn't support

Tags: python, module, load, web-hosting

Is it possible to run a Python module on a website that doesn't support it? For example, my web host iPage has an outdated version of Python (2.5) and a very limited number of modules installed. They won't upgrade Python or install new modules either.

Is there a way to work around this? I would like to use BeautifulSoup in a Python CGI script to parse some HTML pages.

Could Python use a module if it is uploaded to my cgi-bin? Or called remotely?

Comment: BeautifulSoup is quite possible to be deployed. You will need to import all the files from BeautifulSoup into your project. BeautifulSoup however depends on native libraries like `lxml`. It gets tricky deploying these native libraries with extension `.so` or `.dll`. You can make BeautifulSoup but all the features might not be available

Comment: You may be able to install a newer version of python in your local directory.